# How to implement a finite horizon MDP in python?

Tags: python, markov, markov-models, markov-decision-process

I have the following problem from the *Markov Decision Processing* book my Martin L Puterman.
Which I need help with solving in python.

The problem formulation is as such:

> An adult female lion requires
> about 6 kg of meat per day and has a gut capacity of about 30 kg; which means
> that, with a full gut, it can go six days without eating. Zebras have an average
> edible biomass of 164 kg, large enough to meet the food demands of many lions.
> If a female selects to hunt in a group, the probability of a successful kill per
> chase has been observed to increase with group size to a point, and that each
> chase consumes 0.5 kg of energy. Suppose that the probabilities of a successful
> hunt are given by p(l) = 0.15, p(2) = 0.33, p(3) = 0.37,  p(4) = 0.40,  p(5) =
> 0.42, and p ( 2>=6) = 0.43, where p(n) represents thc kill probability per chase
> for lions hunting in a group of size n.
> Formulate this as a Markov decision process, in which the state represents
> the lion’s energy reserves, the action is whether to hunt, and, if so, in what size
> group. Assume one hunt per day and that lion’s objective is to maximize its
> probability of survival over T days. Assume that if the hunt is successful, lions in
> the hunting group share the meat equally.

I've been trying to wrap my head around how to solve it using python.

Currently i have defined my elements as:

S = {0,...,30} -> Representing the lions gut contents (kg).
a = {no_hunt, hunt1, hunt2, hunt3, hunt4, hunt5, hunt6}.
I have excluded the hunt > 6 as that would yield less meal with equal probability of sucess.

I was thinking I would try to implement it in python to simulate over T days.

```
# Constants for the lion's parameters
lion_capacity = 30  # Maximum stomach content
lion_meat_per_day = 6  # Meat required per day
lion_hunt_cost = 0.5  # Meat cost for each hunt
zebra_meat_per_group = 164  # Meat obtained from a successful hunt

# Hunt success probabilities by group size
hunt_success_probabilities = {
    1: 0.15,
    2: 0.33,
    3: 0.37,
    4: 0.4,
    5: 0.42,
    6: 0.43
}

# Number of days to plan for
T = 50

# Initialize state (lion's stomach content) and cumulative reward
state = lion_capacity
cumulative_reward = 0

# Initialize action policy
action_policy = []

# Simulate T days
for day in range(T):
    # Calculate the expected meat yield for each group size
    expected_rewards = []
    for group_size in range(1, 7):
        hunt_prob = hunt_success_probabilities[group_size]
        expected_meat_yield = zebra_meat_per_group / group_size
        adjusted_expected_meat_yield = expected_meat_yield - lion_hunt_cost
        expected_reward = hunt_prob * adjusted_expected_meat_yield
        expected_rewards.append(expected_reward)
    
    # Choose the action that maximizes the expected meat yield while conserving energy
    if lion_capacity >= state - lion_meat_per_day - lion_hunt_cost:
        # If stomach content allows hunting, choose the group size that maximizes expected meat yield
        action = np.argmax(expected_rewards) + 1
        for i in enumerate(expected_rewards):
            print(i)
    else:
        # If stomach content is insufficient for hunting, wait
        action = 0

    # Calculate the reward and update the state based on the chosen action
    if action == 0:  # Wait
        state -= lion_meat_per_day
        reward = 0
    else:
        group_size = action
        hunt_prob = hunt_success_probabilities[group_size]
        # Determine if the hunt is successful
        if np.random.rand() < hunt_prob:
            reward = zebra_meat_per_group / group_size
            state += reward - lion_meat_per_day - lion_hunt_cost
        else:
            reward = -0.5  # Negative reward for unsuccessful hunt
            state -= lion_meat_per_day - lion_hunt_cost

    cumulative_reward += reward

    # Update action policy
    action_policy.append(action)

# Calculate the probability of survival
prob_survival = state / lion_capacity

print(f"Total Reward: {cumulative_reward}")
print(f"Probability of Survival: {prob_survival}")
print(f"Action Policy: {action_policy}")
```

But my results are just always chosing to hunt in a group of 2 or 0.
Furthermore I have absolutely no idea of whether or not my thought process was correct or if it is infact the correct result.